# right order of rewrite rules in an htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, errordocument

I need to have :

http://www.example.com/v1/my-project/  redirected to http://example.com/my-project/

so :

(1) remove the www from the http_host

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(2) remove the 'v1/' part of the request_uri

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/v1/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . %1 [R=301,L]
```

(3) I also want to redirect all 404 to the homepage.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

(4) Finally, all my documents actually reside in a "v2/" folder which hosts the current active website, but i don't want "v2" in the url, just "/"

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v2/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v2/$1 [NC,L]
```

So, here are my rules. My question is: i don't manage (2): it gets redirected to / (because of rule (3) i guess. I think the order of my rules must be faulty but i can't seem to get it right. Can you help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Rule 3" isn't a rule at all, and its order relative to your RewriteRules doesn't matter.  Rule 2 is failing for some other reason.  I'm not sure whether it will address your problem, but I would simplify your rules somewhat by writing them like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^v1/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v2/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /v2/$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first write any rule that is causing an external redirect (`R` flag) and then the other rules. Otherwise an already rewritten URL can be used for an external redirect though it was just intended for an internal redirect.

So I won’t change the order you have right now.