# .htaccess rewrite rule for urls with parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Another url rewrite question, apologies, but having a bit of trouble.

I have removed the `.php` extension from my files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

note: [`app/` is set as the public directory]

note: [`Apache` server]

**Goal**

What I would like is to have `URLs` like such:

`www.example.com/app/user/123` instead of `www.example.com/app/user.php?id=123`

I tried: `RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [R=301,L,NC]` but it just returns an `500 Internal Server Error`

- Also will this affect `GET` and `POST` requests, or will the `php` need to be coded to reflect the url change?

**Links I came across**

[right order of rewrite rules in an htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108995/right-order-of-rewrite-rules-in-an-htaccess-file)

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

[.htaccess RewriteRule to preserve GET URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071155/htaccess-rewriterule-to-preserve-get-url-parameters)

plus many others.

**EDIT**

Does the first rule of removing the`.php` affect the rules that come after it? i.e. stop them from processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering of rules is probably causing this problem. Try these rules in proper order:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/

RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC] 

# hide .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: tried it. It doesn't catch any files with `.php`. 404 not found

Comment: Ah you had `/app/` directory in between. Try edited code now.